# For Loop Will Not Execute C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am making a program that will a number of dice a number of times. I have made a method called 'RollDice'. the method works until the for loop. It returns to the main method after I type 'roll' in the console and i don't know why it won't execute the script in side the for loop. I have marked place where the code stops working. any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dice Roller
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int nos = 6;
            int nod = 1;
            int nor = 1;
            string OP;
            int x = 1;
            while (x == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Random Dice Macine");
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'edit' To Edit Dice Settings");
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'clear' To Clear The Screan");
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' To Close The Aplication");
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'roll' to Roll The Dice");
                Console.Write("-> ");
                OP = Console.ReadLine();
                if (OP == "exit")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else if (OP == "edit")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Number Of Sides On The Dice");
                    Console.Write("->");
                    nos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Number Of Dice");
                    Console.Write("->");
                    nod = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Number Of Roles");
                    Console.Write("->");
                    nor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Setup Compleat! Press Space To Continue.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else if (OP == "clear")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else if (OP == "roll")
                {
                    RollDice(nor, nos, nod);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void RollDice(int nor, int nos, int nod)
        {                                             //Code Works Here
            Random gen = new Random();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            for (int n = 1; n < nod; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < nor; i++)
                {                                     //But Not Here
                    numbers.Add(gen.Next(1, nos));

                }
                foreach (int element in numbers)
                {
                    Console.Write(element + ", ");
                }
                numbers.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run in debug and check the value of `nod`. Looks like it gets passed in as a `1`.

Comment: @Cabe `nor` is also 1.  You're doing this: "while 1 is less than 1, execute this code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In for-loops the counter should start from 0 and not from 1. In your case `nor` and `nod` are equal to 1. That is why the loops are never executed.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see is that if nod or nor is 1 when the program reaches the for loops, the condition to end the loop is already met. Use '<='  instead in the ebd condition.

Answer (score 0):

On line

```
for (int n = 1; n < nod; n++)
```

nod is 1, and n < nod check is termination for loop.
Either set i = 0 or set check n <= nod.